# Parsing word document and inserting in database

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I have a word file:

Question 1: content of question with 
Answer A:
Answer B:
Answer C:
Answer D:

I want to read this file and insert the data in my database
for eg **question1** will go in **Question** column and respective **answers** will go in **answers** column.........

```
string strPath = Server.MapPath("~/Test.doc");
// Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + "\\Test.doc"; 
FileStream fStream = new FileStream (strPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read); 
StreamReader sReader = new StreamReader(fStream); 
//TextBox2.Text = sReader.ReadToEnd(); 
string data1 = sReader.ReadToEnd(); 
sReader.Close(); 
Response.Write(data1);
```

Comment: can you post your code ?

Comment: string strPath = Server.MapPath("~/Test.doc");// Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + "\\Test.doc";
        FileStream fStream = new FileStream
                   (strPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        StreamReader sReader = new StreamReader(fStream);
        //TextBox2.Text = sReader.ReadToEnd();
        string data1 = sReader.ReadToEnd();
        sReader.Close();
        Response.Write(data1);

Comment: But the above code is of no use and i dont knw anything about word file parsing in c#....can u please help me......in acheiving the output

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
string strPath = Server.MapPath("~/Test.doc");
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(strPath, FileMode.Open))
            {
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fs, Encoding.UTF8))
                {
                    string line = null;
                    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(line);
                        if (line.Contains("question"))
                        {
                            //read content here
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```